# 'CSV does not exist' - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulty reading a csv file into the pandas data frame. I am a total newcomer to pandas, and this is preventing me from progressing. I have read the documentation and searched for solutions, but I am unable to proceed. I have tried the following to no avail...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\rcreedon\Desktop\TEST.csv')
pd.read_csv("C:\Users\rcreedon\Desktop\TEST.csv")
```

and similar permutations with/without quotation marks.

It spits out a large composite error that ends in:

```
IOError: File C:\Users
creedon\Desktop\TEST.csv does not exist
```

It seems strange that in the error it misses of the "r" from "rcreedon". Is this what's causing the problem?

Just for the sake of it i also tried

```
pd.read_csv('C:\rcreedon\Desktop\TEST.csv')
```

And again the 'r' was missed when the error was returned.

Sorry to be such a block head, but I'm struggling here....

Any help appreciated.

Comment: switch your slashes ... change `\` to `/` or double up on them (replace `\` with `\\`)... your \r is being interpreted as a carriage return

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"\r" usually is interpreted as a special character and means carriage return. Either add a 'r' prefix to your string literals which prevents this special sequence from being interpreted (e.g. `path = r"foo\rar"`), or, as already suggested, just use a normal slash as path delimiter. Python is intelligent enough for it to also work on Windows :-)

Comment: woah!!!! that's a silent killer man!! thanks for this!

Answer (score 6):

Just use a raw string:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rcreedon\Desktop\TEST.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You may need to check and see how many tabs are in your excel file. I had a problem where Excel 2010 would not save the entire workbook as a csv file and I had to save each tab individually. After that I was able to open using Pandas. I would suggest using r":C\pathname..." too.